# Android Activity transition from left to right with ease in and out curve

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions, activity-transition

I'm trying to add a **transition animation** between `Activities` in `Android`. As I'm coming from iOS I really like the transition slide from right to left when entering a new `UIViewController/Activity` (and left to right when leaving). I been trying to mock this animation but all I succeeded to do is to add a linear transition between `Activities`. This through `getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);` where `R.anim.exit` and `R.anim.enter` is the animation files for entering and exiting a view. This is how R.anim.enter looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">

<translate
    android:duration="225"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

As I can see there is no way to add **curved transitions** in this file and I haven't found how to add **curved transition** to `Activities` online either.

Is there anyone who knows how to add a **curved transitions** between `Activities` similar to iOS `curveEaseInOut` animation in Android?

Comment: follow this link :-> http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding the `android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"` key in the **anim XML.**

Final code could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="225"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```